# MATLAB (index must be a positive integer or logical.)

Tags: matlab

i cannot solve the problem here!
i change V(0)=0 to V(1)=0 then 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.' occured

```
i=0; 
m=70;
C=10;
g=9.81;
V(0)=0;
for t=0:0.25:50
   V(i+1)=V(i)+(g-(C*V(i))/m)*(t(i+1)-t(i));
   i=i+1;
end
plot(V(i),t(i))
```

Comment: Array index in MatLab starts from 1, while you have `V(0)`.

Comment: yes, i search for it and i got it! Then i change the values for v(1).but Index exceeds matrix dimension fail occur

Comment: You also have `t(i)`: at the first iteration of the for loop, `i` is still `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some error in your code:

- the array `V` is initialized starting form `0` while in MatLab the array's index starts from `1`
- since you've initialized `i=0` for the above reason, in the first iteration of the loop, you try to access `t(0)`
- calling the `plot` function as `plot(V(i),t(i))` you will plot only one point, moreover, incrementing `i` at the end of the for loop, makes `V(i)` and `t(i)` being not actually computed
- in the loop you can not access `t(i+1)` if `t` is the loop index, since it ha not been yet evaluated

You can modify your code as follows:

```
% i=0; 
m=70;
C=10;
g=9.81;
% V(0)=0;
% Initialize the arrayV
V(1)=0;
% Define the time increment
dt=0.25
% Define the time samples
t=0:dt:50
% for t=0:0.25:50
% Loop over the time samples
for idx=1:length(t)-1
%    V(i+1)=V(i)+(g-(C*V(i))/m)*(t(i+1)-t(i));
   V(idx+1)=V(idx)+(g-(C*V(idx))/m)*dt;
%    i=i+1;
end
% plot(V(i),t(i))
plot(t,V)
grid minor
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Speed')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is array V is declared somewhere else? It seems you are trying to access first element of it but array has not been initialized yet. 
I don't know whether value of that array must be calculated or hardcoded, so please see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com for more

Comment: actually i am trying to make a v/t graph of free fall movement